# How to write $(0,1)$ as a closed intersection?

Tags: general-topology

If I have $(0,1]$, how is this written as the intersection of closed sets? Is it the intersection of $[1/j, 1]$, or $[-1/j,1$], or something else?

Comment: In the usual topology on the reals?

Answer (score 4):

The intersection of closed sets is closed. And $(0,1]$ is not closed (in the usual topology of the reals). So it cannot be done.

Comment: isn't it clopen?

Comment: If it's not closed, it's certainly not clopen (= closed *and* open).

Comment: Ignoring the right side of the interval, is it not possible to write $(a = \bigcap_{n \ge 1} [a_n$?

Comment: but it's not open either then because $1$ is not an interior point

Comment: Indeed, but it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Seth, no. Believe the argument.

Comment: @Seth: If $a_n$ is an increasing sequence with $a_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$, then, using your notation, $\cap_{n \geq 1} [a_n = [a$, not $(a$. This is because $a$ is contained in all of the intervals being intersected.